# Apache2 relative paths not working

Tags: apache, server, webserver, apache2, relative-path

Good Morning,
I am currently setting up and apache2 server on my raspberry pi. My `index.html` file is in the directory `/var/www/html` and the file is loading fine when I go to the IP address. However, the images located in `/var/www/html/img` are not loading. The html is like this: `<img alt="image1" src="img/picture1.png">`. When I right click on the alternative image icon, and select open image in new tab, I get:

```
You don't have permission to access /img/picture1.png on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

How can I prevent this and make the user able to access the image?

Many thanks,

Comment: Look at the access rights of the directory and files, and set them to be readable for all.

Comment: The `img` folder is in the same directory as `index.html` so it has permission as everything in /var/www/html is able to view.

Comment: I think the problem is with the relative path

Comment: Without more details one can not tell the answer .... why should img be readable if index.html is .... every file/folder can have its own permissions.

Comment: I made the entire /var/www/html folder accessible from anyone so I don't see why it isn't allowing me to see it.

Comment: Did you try making the directory executable?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168298/discussion-between-marmadukeandbob-and-yesthatismyname).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
chmod -R 755 /img/
```

this will set the permission for all files in the folder readable and executable for all, and also writable by the owner.

The output will be in the form

```
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root             0 Apr  5 12:38 picture1.jpg
```